# How to create JobConsumer in Sling?

Tags: java, aem, apache-felix, sling

According to Apache Sling official site(https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/apache-sling-eventing-and-job-handling.html#job-consumers), this is the way to write JobConsumer.

```
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
import org.apache.sling.event.jobs.Job;
import org.apache.sling.event.jobs.consumer.JobConsumer;

@Component
@Service(value={JobConsumer.class})
@Property(name=JobConsumer.PROPERTY_TOPICS, value="my/special/jobtopic",)
public class MyJobConsumer implements JobConsumer {

    public JobResult process(final Job job) {
        // process the job and return the result
        return JobResult.OK;
    }
}
```

However @Service and @Property are both deprecated annotations.
I want to know the proper way to create JobConsumer.
Does anyone know how to write a code equivalent to the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scr annotations are deprecated in AEM and it is recommended to use the official OSGi Declarative Services annotations going forward. There is a [seminar by Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kt/eseminars/gems/Using-OSGi-R7-in-AEM.html) on using the OSGi R7 annotations.

The new way of writing the same would be

```
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.sling.event.jobs.Job;
import org.apache.sling.event.jobs.consumer.JobConsumer;

@Component(
    immediate = true,
    service = JobConsumer.class,
    property = {
        JobConsumer.PROPERTY_TOPICS +"=my/special/jobtopic"
    }
)
public class MyJobConsumer implements JobConsumer {

    public JobResult process(final Job job) {
        // process the job and return the result
        return JobResult.OK;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the below blog. I have tried to explain it here.

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/aem-how-write-sling-jobs-aem-veena-vikraman